# How does a battery ( primary cell ) work?

Tags: batteries

I'm having an hard time understanding primary cells.
There are plenty of videos and explanations about the reactions that happen inside the battery, but you must have a strong background in chemistry to really understand them.
Instead, I would love to have a description that abstracts from the chemicals details, and still manages to explain its basic working princeples!
I would like it to address the following questions/doubts:

- Electrons flow form higher potential to lower potential so, when you buy a 
  battery, is an electric field already there, before connecting it to a wire?
  (I presume yes)
- So,How is this field created? Are the electrons at the top and the protons at 
  the bottom, or just electrons at the top and the bottom is neutral? How are
  electrons kept together in the same place before connecting the battery 
  to the wire? What does prevent them to flow inside the battery?
- How does the battery pump up the electrons? and at which rate?
  What makes it burn out? and after many cycles does it burn out?

I know there are a lot of questions but my mind is exploding. I don't expect everything to be abstracted from the chemicals but as long as you can through analogies, or intuitive principles, i'd love that. Anyway the main intent of the answer must be addressing the doubts listed.

Comment: That's not a simple topic, but at it's core it's all about the relative [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity) of the metals and electrolyte.

Comment: If it's a primary cell it burns out after one cycle, by definition. (But yes there are ways of using some primary cells as bad secondary cells by partially recharging them a few times)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*is an electric field already there, before connecting it to a wire?*

**Yes** otherwise no current would be able to flow through a load connected to the battery contacts. The electric field is what makes the electrons move and the moving of the electrons is what contains the energy.

Electrons have a negative charge, so an excess of electrons is present on the negative or Cathode (-) connection of the battery. On the positive or Anode (+) terminal, there is an equal but positive charge (due to missing electrons) present.

Note that the total charge is **zero**, so the amount of surplus electrons at the (-) contact is equal to the amount missing at the (+) contact.

This **charge** (electrons or those *missing* electrons) is actually **insignificant**, it does not contain much energy. The significant part is that **if** you connect the (+) and (-) contacts, a **current** can flow because the charges want to neutralize.

However, the chemistry going around in the battery then starts "moving" **ions* (which can have one or more surplus or missing electrons) from the (+) contact to the (-) contact. This process consumes certain chemical substances and forming others while electrons are "made free" and end up at the (-) contact (the Cathode).

The electrons **do** flow inside the battery; they are transported by the **ions** from anode (+) to cathode (-), completing the current loop. To make them flow this way, energy is needed. This energy comes from the Chemical reaction going on in the battery.

If there is no load connected to the battery, the electrons remain stuck at the Cathode. They accumulate there until a certain voltage is reached, when the Chemical reaction (which produces the electrons) slows down and stops. The chemical reaction stops because it cannot "deliver" the "free" electrons anymore. It can't deliver the free electrons anymore because it requires increasingly more energy for as the potential increases. Once a given potential is reached, the process stops. When a load is connected, it lowers the potential (slightly), which allows more electrons to be "freed", which starts the process again.

The rate of electrons generated depends on the current through the load. Look up the definitions of electric current, its relation to charge, and the charge of a single electron. Then you can calculate how many electrons are involved in making a current of 1 Ampere flow for example (1 Ampere corresponds to 6.25 × 10<sup>18</sup> electrons per second).

Batteries should not *burn out*; if they burn, you're using them wrong. They are used up or **depleted**. That's because the Chemical reaction needed uses up the Chemicals inside then battery and replaces them with something else—like any Chemical reaction.

In Primary batteries, there is no way back; when the needed chemicals are used up, the battery has become useless.

In rechargeable batteries, the Chemical process can be reversed by forcing the electrons (on the back of the Ions) to flow the opposite way (from Cathode to Anode) inside the battery.

How long a battery lasts depends on how you use it. A situation that quickly drains the battery uses less total energy than one where the load needs a small current. Look in battery datasheets to see the difference; there can be up to a factor 5 difference in available energy!

*Note that I am not a battery expert, if there are any flaws in my reasoning please mention them in a comment.*

Comment: Isn’t cathode to anode the “normal” or actual direction the electrons flow?

Comment: "Burn out" is a common term in certain parts when referring to a chemical reaction completing, and is actually accurate where the reaction involves the oxidization of a chemical. Good answer though +1 from moi.

Comment: @SolarMike When a battery is discharging, the current that flows **outside** the battery, though the load, it flows from anode (+) to cathode (-) so the electrons flow in the reverse direction from - to +. **Inside** the battery it is the reverse so the electrons flow from + to -, anode to cathode, right? Perhaps you think "outside current" while I talk about inside current?

Comment: "*The electrons do flow inside the battery only from + (Anode) to - (Cathode) so in the opposite direction from how they flow through the load.*" I blinked at this too. I think it might be better as "*The electrons do flow inside the battery from + (anode) to - (cathode) to complete the current loop.*"

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to say "electrons flow inside the battery" - *ions* move inside the battery! Otherwise you have to answer the questions "why don't the electrons take a shortcut inside the battery" and "what causes the electrons to move"?

Comment: @Transistor Good suggestion, I updated to include your suggestion.

Comment: @pjc50 Good suggestion as well, updated to emphasize that Ions do the actual electron transport inside the battery.

Comment: @pjc50 it is probably not a good idea to delve too deeply into the what does what within the battery. Truth be told, it is not a simple thing and is really not well understood, except perhaps theoretically by quantum physicists. It is enough to simply state "Due to a chemical reaction, atoms and electrons are separated such that the positive terminal becomes ionized and electrons gather on the negative terminal and that the electrolyte acts like a diode preventing the two from recombining." How all that actually happens is really irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying helping out and taking your time. I do really appreciate this.

Answer (score 8):

Normally I would say "ignore the electrons" while trying to understand electronics, but this is one of those cases where they actually matter.

I'll use a standard [alkaline battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery) as my example. Chemistry:

```
Zn(s) + 2OH−(aq) → ZnO(s) + H2O(l) + 2e− [Eoxidation° = +1.28 V]
2MnO2(s) + H2O(l) + 2e− → Mn2O3(s) + 2OH−(aq) [Ereduction° = +0.15 V]
```

There are three elements. An anode (zinc), connected to the battery negative terminal; a cathode (manganese oxide) connected to battery positive, and an electrolyte (potassium hydroxide, which is the "alkali" of the name). The electrolyte in any battery is a liquid which sits between the electrodes.

"Electronegativity" is the tendency of chemicals to attract or lose electrons. The top reaction is quite keen to shed its two electrons and dump them onto the anode. It does this until a field of approximately 1.28V builds up between the electrode and the solution, at which point the reaction no longer has enough energy to overcome the field and push electrons onto the anode. Similarly the other end builds up a small field.

Note that the electrolyte is *not* conductive, at least not in the same way that metals are. There aren't electrons floating freely in the electrolyte. There are however ions, carrying a positive (potassium) or negative (hydroxide) charge. The ions are free to travel from one electrode to the other.

When does it run out? When the Zinc has all been oxidised to zinc oxide, or manganese dioxide has run out.

Comment: Again, as I commented in Bimps answer, it is a mistake to try to nail this down too much. This description is a simply a model that describes the behavior.

Comment: Although I agree that the Question doesn't ask for too much Chemistry, I do think that this answer in combination with my answer describes the situation well enough. I didn't want to include the Chemistry formulas but they're now in this answer which I like.

Answer (score 2):

There are already great technical answers to this question so I'll just add a comparison to a water system.

Consider the following system with two water containers:
[image]

The left container contains water that is at higher potential than the (none-existent) water in the right container.

*There isn't an (electric) field* between the containers (or the electrodes in the battery) but there is a potential difference.

What we do when we draw a current out of the battery is basically providing a way for the electrons to flow from the high potential side to the low potential side.

If we connect the two water containers, we allow water to flow from the high potential region to low potential region, and can use the potential difference to do work (by putting a water wheel as in a water mill) between the containers.
[image]

The rate of the electrons/water flowing between the containers is determined by the potential difference as well as the resistance of the connector between the containers.

The resistance in the water case is determined by the diameter of the pipe as well as the friction against the pipe walls.

When we deplete the system, the electrons/water in both containers is at the same potential and there is no longer any flow between the containers.
[image]

---

*Note:* This type of analogy doesn't always work. We have for example not thought about the separator/membrane that the battery system need.

Answer (score 1):

A comment on the discharging. Batteries do not just suddenly run out of charge and fail. The decline in available energy is gradual. The reaction can be considered similar to corrosion or rusting, and the spent byproducts from earlier chemical reactions will build up and get in the way of additional reactions, slowing the overall reactivity.

As the chemical reaction slows towards the end of life, the voltage difference at the terminals will decline. Due to the formula Volts x Amps = Watts, as the voltage declines the amperage draw from the battery will increase to compensate.

There is an amperage draw limit due to the thickness of the battery terminals, the device terminal wires, and the available reactive surface area of the anode and cathode. One of these will eventually restrict the available amperage, and at that point the voltage will drop rapidly, resulting in a brownout condition that causes the device to malfunction or fail.

A battery which is used in a high current application and appears to be dead after a short period of time can continue to function normally if reused for a low current application, because the slowed cell reactivity can still maintain a sufficiently useful high voltage if the amperage draw is low.

,

Also very cold temperatures can affect the available voltage, because the chemical reactions are slowed. A vehicle battery chilled to -40C/F may only be able to dimly illuminate the instrument panel and very slowly crank the starter motor, because the chemical reaction speed is too slow to maintain a high voltage differential across the battery terminals. However vehicle batteries typically have a very large and spongy surface area allowing for high amperage draw even when the chemical reactivity is slowed.

Consider a typical vehicle starter motor which is rated for approximately 1500 watts:

- At normal room temperature a fully charged six-cell lead-acid vehicle battery can provide 13.6 volts at 110 amps to output 1500 watts.
- At -40C the available voltage differential of a fully charged battery can drop as low as 6 volts. The amperage draw then rises 250 amps to compensate for the low voltage, which is what is referred to as "cold cranking amps" on vehicle batteries.

This is also why vehicle starter wires and battery terminals are typically very thick and heavy, to pass this unusually large current in severe cold conditions.